# What's the difference between ListByResourceGroup() and GetByResourceGroup() in azure sdk?

Tags: azure, azure-sdk

When working with azure sdk I see `ListByResourceGroup()`, `GetByResourceGroup()` return the same value. What is the difference between them? If I want to get all information of vm in my subcriptions, what function should I use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
T GetByResourceGroup(string resourceGroupName, string name)

IEnumerable<T> ListByResourceGroup(string resourceGroupName)
```

So, if you use GetByResourceGroup, you need to provide 2 parameters. One is the resource group name, the other is the name for the VM.  And you will only get the target VM.

However, ListByResourceGroup only reqiure for the resource group name. And you will be able to get all the VMs in the resource group.

If you want to get all the VMs, you can use the following as a sample:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IAzure azure = Azure.Authenticate("path_to_auth_file").WithDefaultSubscription();

        var vms = azure.VirtualMachines.List();
        foreach( var vm in vms)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(vm.Name);
        }
    }
```

I just simply output the VM's name, you can do what you want in the foreach.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to existing answer, in Azure SDK `LIST` always gets all resources from subscription or resource group (usually all resources of the same type), whereas `GET` is used to retrieve a specific resource (if it exists), hence you need to specify the `resourceGroup` AND the resource `name`.

I'd be inclined to think this is universal. If you think about it for a second those verbs in english are meant exactly for that.